# Http Request to a local node server from local angular project CORS ERR

Tags: node.js, angular, http, cors

I am making a local project, I use angular 6 form that run on node server **localhost:4200/** and nodeJs that run on node server but at different port **localhost:2000**

The problem is getting CORS security error even though I prepared the nodejs to accept the request.

**Angular Code**

```
  register(regData){
    return this.httpClient.post(this.url,regData);
  }
```

**npm install cors --save** // intsall cors (NodeJs)

**NodeJs**

```
const express  = require('express')
,cors = require('cors')
,app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const productR = require('./routes/product');

// middleware
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var originsWhitelist = [
    'http://localhost:4200',      //this is my front-end url for development
    'http://127.0.0.1:4200'
  ];
  var corsOptions = {
    origin: function(origin, callback){
          var isWhitelisted = originsWhitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1;
          callback(null, isWhitelisted);
    },
    credentials:true
  }
  app.use(cors(corsOptions));
  app.use('/products', productR);
```

**ERROR MESSAGE**

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'localhost:2000/products/create' from
>   origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross
>   origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data,
>   chrome, chrome-extension, https.

Comment: Have you tried to change the url to `http://localhost:2000` (instead of `localhost:2000`) in your client-side code? Make sure that `this.url` (in `this.httpClient.post(this.url,regData);`) starts with `http://...`

Comment: @MaxMartynov thank you, this solved my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message means that the URL which you use for requests from the client-side contains incorrect protocol. In your case, there was no protocol in the URL at all.

So, the solution of your problem is to use `http://localhost:2000` instead of `localhost:2000`.

The protocol is an important part of the URL because there are big differences between the protocols. For example, your URL could look like `file:///localhost...` or `ftp://localhost...` and so on. So it will be better to always define it directly.