# CORS policy block for http get with relative path after building Angular application

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following function:

```
loadSettings() :Observable<ISettings> {
    return this.http.get<ISettings>('./assets/config.ini').pipe(
        catchError(this.handleError);
    );
}
```

This works well when I host my Angular application with `ng serve` command in terminal. However, if I build my project with `ng build` and launch *index.html* I receive the following errors:

[image: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///C:/ng-client-ui/dist/ng-client-ui/assets/config.ini' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome-extension, edge, https, chrome-untrusted.]

I do not understand the error message, since the request is from the get method of the browsers `HttpClient` class. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54266425/http-request-to-a-local-node-server-from-local-angular-project-cors-err) post suggests that I include the protocol to the url of the request, but I am using a relative path.

I suspect that I might need to add headers to my GET request, but my attempts were in vain so far. Any ideas?

Comment: These errors look weird. Weird enough to let you know that this is not the way it should work. Use a lightweight server, for example [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server).

Comment: @OctavianMărculescu Do built angular apps need to be hosted? Isn't the result of the build a simple html and js connected to it?

Comment: Yes, the output of the build are just static files, but you still need a server to serve you the static files (for the client application I mean). In full stack applications, is common have your angular static files served by the same server that you use for your backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone finding this thread: as per the comment of Octavian Mărculescu my issue was that the built angular app was not hosted and thus the static files were not served to my browser, which resulted in the errors presented; e.g. see the "origin 'null' has been blocked" part of the message in OP.

See this [link](https://www.geekstrick.com/build-and-host-angular-10-application/?msclkid=a191709dc22811ec8cb3cb963003d70f) for further info on hosting your Angular applications.